# how to use tcmalloc in programs with dynamic libraries

Tags: memory-management, linker, malloc

I use tcmalloc in my main program A by adding -ltcmalloc in linking time. When A starts, it will dynamically load several precompiled .so files, such as B.so, C.so. 
then, will the malloc() in B.so and C.so use tcmalloc automatically?

Comment: By "dynamic" do you mean at load time or at runtime (with `dlopen`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When A starts, it will dynamically load several precompiled .so files, such as B.so, C.so. then, will the malloc() in B.so and C.so use tcmalloc automatically?

Depends on your OS, and possibly on whether you are using archive or shared version of `libtcmalloc`.

On Linux (and other `ELF` platforms), using `libtcmalloc.so`, the answer is yes.
On Linux, using `libtcmalloc.a`, the answer is "most likely". To make it a "definite yes", add `-rdynamic` to the link line for the main executable.
On AIX, the answer is no, unless you add a bunch of non-trivial options to `B.so` and `C.so` link lines.